# How to get different IPs on cloned machines with VirtualBox?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ip-address

I created a virtual machine with a CLI iso of Lubuntu 16.04 with **VirtualBox**. Now I need several machines with the **same characteristics** (but different IPs, in order to test a C network application I wrote), so I **cloned** the first one.

I changed the network settings of both machines so they both would have a **network adapter attached to an internal network with the same name**.

If I try to run `$ ifconfig` on both machines I get the same IP (i.e. `10.0.2.15`). Why? How to get different IPs?

Here's what's inside `/etc/network/interfaces` of both machines:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
```

Comment: When you cloned the VM, did you check 'Reinitialize the MAC address of all network cards' ?

Comment: @user4556274 yes I did! Indeed MAC addresses are different, just IP is the same.

Comment: @Robb1 Are the images using DHCP or static addresses? If they're configured for static addresses you'll get the same one each time. If they're configured for DHCP and have different MAC addresses the DHCP server should handle them.

Comment: @Centimane thanks for your answer. How to check if they are using DHCP? I can't find it in network settings

Comment: @Robb1 https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html#ip-addressing see the dynamic IP address assignment and static IP address assignment sections. Basically check `/etc/network/interfaces` and look for `iface [interface] inet dhcp` or `iface [interface] inet static`.

Comment: @Centimane I edited my OP with the text inside `/etc/network/interfaces` but there's not `static` there

Comment: @Robb1 Alright then, in that case, are you running a DHCP server anywhere in this internal network? There's one built into VirtualBox: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-dhcpserver

Comment: You could use `vagrant` to spin up a bunch of virts with varying IP address details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was initialize a **DHCP server** with the proper `netname` (e.g. `mynetwork`) running the following command:

`$ VBoxManage dhcpserver add --netname mynetwork --ip 11.11.11.1 --netmask 255.255.255.0 --lowerip 11.11.11.3 --upperip 11.11.11.20 --enable`

Of course also the ips depend on what you need.

Comment: Can you explain how you chose the name `mynetwork` and the numbers `11.11.11.x`? This doesn't look like the same network that you have in the question

Answer (score 4):

The 10.0.2.15 address indicates that you have your VM on the NAT network.  This is probably not what you want, it basically allows a machine access to the world but no direct connection to other machines (physical or virtual).

When you clone the machine, you have the option of resetting the MAC address.  Do this.

For Network type, it depends on your needs.  Do these VMs need to access each other? The host machine? Internet? Other machines on your host machine's LAN?

Here's a c/p of some info from an answer I gave for a similar question -

Network connectivity to your VM - assuming of course that it has a properly configured service to connect to - depends on what network type you've chosen in the VM settings.

1) NAT - this does what it says. Unfortunately, it doesn't create a matching address on your host machine. The only way to connect is to forward individual ports, just like you would on your home router. This is done in the manager interface, in the settings for the machine, on the networks tab. If you have "NAT" selected as the network type and the card is active/enabled, the Port Forwarding button will be active and available.

2) Bridged - this bridges across one of your ethernet devices in the host machine, and connects directly to the network as if it were plugged in to a jack somewhere. HOWEVER... some work places, schools, etc. do not allow multiple MAC addresses to communicate through a single managed switch port, and if that is the case on whatever LAN you are connecting to it Won't Work.

3) Host Only - this creates a virtual network between your host machine and the guest(s). There is a dhcp service available, but it won't provide a gateway. If you want your guests to connect, you'll need to set up NAT/etc on the host machine and provide access that way.

4) Internal only - this connects machines to a virtual internal dumb switch. No DHCP service, no gateway access, nothing. Oh, and no matching adapter on your host machine.

What I do for a lot of practice/playground/experimentation is set up one machine with 2 interfaces - one on bridged, and one internal. I then turn that into a router machine, with a fake domain (fake.tld) DNS service, DHCP, caching DNS service for the world, etc. and then spin up other VMS to actually experiment and do things with on the internal only network.

Answer (score 1):

For my setup I used `dhclient` to release the IP address.  I used the `-r` option followed by the interface name.

```
sudo dhclient -r enp0s3
```

Then to get the new IP just executed `sudo dhclient` without any options.

Please note that my clones were built using their own MAC address, which is an option when building your clones.